# Error redirecting to paypal express checkout

Tags: paypal

I am implementing PAYPAL Express checkout in and get this error when redirecting to the paypal payment page from my site.

```
ACK=Failure&L_ERRORCODE0=81002&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Unspecified%20Method&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Method%20Specified%20is%20not%20Supported&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error
```

This happens after successfully calling the setExpressCheckout method and successfully getting a token in return. I am at a loss as to what could be the issue. The url is in the form of :

```
https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token="+token+"&force_sa=true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the endpoint (which I picked from the PayPal documentation) is wrong. I received an answer from paypal to change the endpoint to `https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?`.

Answer (score 0):

Express Checkout consists of 3 API calls:  SetExpressCheckout, GetExpressCheckoutDetails, and DoExpressCheckoutPayment.  Which one is failing on you?  Can you provide the raw request samples for each of those calls that you're sending to PayPal?

That error is pretty specific so you must have an invalid method being sent in the request.

From what I'm seeing, it looks like you must be redirecting the user to the API endpoint instead of the URL you should be using, which would be something like this:  https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&useraction=continue&token=EC-0EA317576R7387023

Comment: The error comes after the after SetExpressCheckout returns with the required token and after I effect the redirect.

Comment: Ok, well you must be making another API call instead of simply redirecting if you're getting that error.  That error is basically saying you sent a request to PayPal's API endpoint without a valid value (probably no value at all) for the METHOD parameter.

Comment: I should mention that the error is actually displayed in the browser return and nothing's shown in the IDE